# MVC with tabs (linking gui and data classes)

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I am in the process of planning out a rock paper scissors "game" using swing that will follow the MVC design. The purpose of this is to learn more about how MVC works, and not to be useful/functional. The design I have right now has a form that allows the user to create new games, and then the games appear in a JTabbedPane so that the user can have multiple games running at a time. I have 2 questions about this system:

Should the rock paper scissors logic be handled in the model, or should the logic be handled in the controller? I have an enum that represents the different choices and an algorithm to find out who won, but I am a little confused as to where that should actually be handled.

My second question might be a little confusing. The way I have it planned out right now is I have a JPanel called GamePanel and each game has one of these as a tab in the TabbedPane. What is the "proper" way to link my GamePanel with my Game data that comes from the model? In the simplest case, each game has a GamePanel and a Game object for storing the data. What is the correct way to link these together in the controller so that through an event system I can easily take user input and modify the correct game based on it? The first thing that comes to mind would be a HashMap(GamePanel, Game) but that doesn't seem to be very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

> Should the rock paper scissors logic be handled in the model, or should the logic be handled in the controller?

One of the issues with MVC logic in Swing is that the place where the code resides is not always the place where the code is executed.

The rock / paper / scissors logic will be executed as a part of the controller.  The code will more likely reside in the model class, as that's where the values of the players choice of rock, paper, or scissors will be found.

> What is the "proper" way to link my GamePanel with my Game data that comes from the model?

You'll have an instance of the Game data for each active game you have.  You can store them in a List, as the order of the games is important.  Your List would be defined in another model class, say AllGames.  There would be one instance of AllGames, which would be passed to your Swing classes for them to use to retrieve game values.

Take a look at this article, [Dice Game](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=460), to see how the MVC architecture is used in a more elaborate game.

Comment: Shouldn't the view never reference the model? (Referring to your answer to the second question) - or is this more of a thing that depends on who you ask?

Comment: @Phiction: How is the view going to display values, unless the view gets them from the model?  The view shouldn't set or modify values in the model.  That's the job of the controller.

Comment: My understanding of it has always been the controller updates the data and then tells the view what to change without actually passing it objects from the model (not importing anything from model)